# Jest not executing every test for each element in array

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm having a problem where Jest isn't running the test for each item in the array.

```
const newUniqueLangs = ['de', 'de', 'de', 'de', 'de', 'de', 'it', 'it', 'it', 'it', 'it', 'it', 'nl', 'nl', 'nl', 'nl', 'nl', 'nl', 'fr', 'fr', 'fr', 'fr', 'fr', 'fr', 'en', 'en', 'en', 'en', 'en', 'en' ]
```

The reason for the duplicated items in this array is due that each trigger should have it's own 'language', so I have to duplicate it depending on how many triggers there are in userTriggerFile. In this case there should be 6 for each language.

```
// UserTriggerFile is a big dictionary and I'm accessing each message in this

// Trigger messages is just an array of messages.

it('has a valid triggers for each particular language', () => {
    newUniqueLangs.forEach(function (lang) {
        for (const key in userTriggerFile) {
            userTriggerFile[key].forEach(function (obj) {
                if (obj.Message) {
                    if (obj.LocaleMessage) {
                        expect(triggerMessages).toContain(`${obj.Message + '-' + lang}`)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

The problem is that this test should be executed for every item in this array but it isn't. I believe this is a problem with the nested for loop. I've been looking at 'test.each' in Jest and maybe it's because I am missing this?

Comment: How did you tell the test aren't executed for every item?

Answer (score 1):

Answer, I was misplacing the 'it' statement:

```
describe('test triggers', () => {
    newUniqueLangs.forEach(function (lang) {
        for (const key in userTriggerFile) {
            userTriggerFile[key].forEach(function (obj) {
                if (obj.Message) {
                    if (obj.LocaleMessage) {
                      it('has a valid triggers for each particular language', () => {
                        expect(triggerMessages).toContain(`${obj.Message + '-' + lang}`)     
                      })
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```